# How to use keyboard events in React to make a widget keyboard?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

This is my code

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

const alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];

export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState<number | null>(null);
  const selectedRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const selectLetter = (i: number) => {
    if (selected === i) {
      setSelected(null);
    } else {
      setSelected(i);
    }
  };

  const navigate = (
    event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>,
    letter: string,
    i: number
  ) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      if (i === selected) {
        setSelected(null);
      } else {
        setSelected(i);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      tabIndex={-1}
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        gap: "5px",
        flexWrap: "wrap"
      }}
    >
      {alphabet.map((letter: string, i: number) => (
        <div
          ref={selected === i ? selectedRef : null}
          onClick={() => selectLetter(i)}
          onKeyDown={(event) => navigate(event, letter, i)}
          tabIndex={selected === i ? 0 : -1}
          style={{
            border: "1px solid blue",
            padding: "30px",
            backgroundColor: i === selected ? "blue" : "white",
            color: i === selected ? "white" : "black",
            fontWeight: "bolder",
            cursor: "pointer"
          }}
        >
          {letter}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have the letters "A", "B", "C", "D", "E". If I click them, then they get highlighted. Only one letter can be selected at a time and it could be deselected if you click them again. That part works fine.

The part I'm having trouble with is integrating keyboard to work too.

I also want to be able to use my keyboard and do the same thing but instead with keyboard. Like lets say by default the tabIndex is on "A". if I press enter it would highlight "A"

[image]

If I press enter again (deselects 'A')

[image]

I should also be able to use arrow key to move the tabIndex, so for example if I use the right key then it would be focused on "B". And then when I press enter, then B should be highlighted

[image]

I should freely be able to navigate A,B,C,D,E with my keyboard.

I'm reading the tabindex article in mozilla and I just cant figure it out. I somewhat have the enter working but after one press I'm unsure how to get the tabindex to move.

myplayground: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-aryabhata-vxoi90?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1358

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want your `tabIndex` be `0` for all elements so you can navigate through them in sequential order with the `Tab` key. That's the only purpose of the `tabIndex` attribute here.

Then, for navigating through arrow keys you can check for the `ArrowLeft` / `ArrowRight` `event.key`, and then `.focus()` the previous / next element:

```js
if (event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
  document.querySelectorAll("#root div div")[i-1]?.focus();
}
if (event.key === "ArrowRight") {
  document.querySelectorAll("#root div div")[i+1]?.focus();
}
```

Here's your updated codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-tdd-8g3prn?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Anyway to do this with useRef?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with useRef?

Comment: I cant use `document.querySelectorAll` in my main assignment (larger version of this), so to replace that I guess

Comment: Then you can put a ref on the parent element, and use `parentRef.current?.children[i + 1]?.focus();` instead. I've updated the codesandbox.